# Сan one use multiple который clauses within a single sentence?

Tags: грамматика

Is it grammatical to have multiple который clauses within a single sentence?

For example, if I have an English sentence like:

> "I read a book that my friend recommended to me called 'Life'"

My instinct would be to write something like:

> Я прочитал книгу, которую мой друг мне рекомендовал, которая называется "Жизнь".

Is this type of sentence allowed in Russian?

I often want to add multiple clarifying clauses, but I haven't come across examples using two который clauses in the wild yet.

Comment: "Вот два петуха, которые будят того пастуха, который бранится с коровницей строгою, которая доит корову безрогую, лягнувшую старого пса без хвоста, который за шиворот треплет кота, который пугает и ловит синицу, которая часто ворует пшеницу, которая в тёмном чулане хранится в доме, который построил Джек."

Comment: Hah that's awesome! I googled where that's from -- looks like it's time to watch "дом который построил джек"

Comment: @Headcrab: both *который* in the op's question refer to the book, it's not a chain like in the poem

Comment: @Quassnoi OK, how about this: "... кота, который пугает и ловит синицу, который умеет косплеить куницу, который весною играет в "Зарницу", который с ружьём охраняет границу..." - all the "который" are about the cat, but it still feels sort of legit.

Comment: @Headcrab: rhymes and repetition are like sugar, they dumb down your taste of language. The original boils down to *пёс, который треплет кота, который ловит синицу*. Who is catching the bird, the dog or the cat? It kinda seems obvious in a long repetitive series, but that's the series which make it obvious, not the grammar. Your example *кот, который ловит синицу, который играет в Зарницу* has the same structure but the gender mismatch makes in unequivocal.

Comment: From your example you omit "that" before "called" for example. Awesome example provided by @Headcrab from "This is the house that Jack built" so called cumulative tale. The "that" or "который" points to the previous object (or subject). It does not make sense to repeat this word because by adding a new phrase in the sentence you force the listener or reader to think which object (or subject) you meant. This is exactly the beauty of that folktale with chained pointers creating the complexity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"I read a book that my friend recommended to me called 'Life'"

Я прочитал книгу, которую мой друг мне рекомендовал, которая называется "Жизнь"

Well, it *is* grammatically correct, but it sounds a bit awkward.
A translator would have avoided the overuse of subordinate clauses.

Я прочитал книгу под названием «Жизнь», которую порекомендовал друг.

По совету друга я прочитал книгу, которая называется «Жизнь».

По совету друга я прочитал книгу (под названием) «Жизнь»

Answer (score 4):

Well, no police is going to come for you in this particular situation in Russia — there's no language police to speak of after all, but these kinds of combinations are highly unlikely in Russian without using "и", so it would sound more natural as:

> Я прочитал книгу, которую мой друг мне рекомендовал и которая
> называется "Жизнь".

Still, even with this syntax it sounds slightly, I don't know... *bookish* compared to something like:

> Я прочитал книгу, которую мой друг мне рекомендовал, [она] "Жизнь" называется.